# Is there a way to include non-exporting js library into vue cli project?

Tags: vue.js

For the past 2 days I've been trying to include a non-exporting js library into my vue project and it seems to fail every time. The closest I've got to a working thing is with `import *`. It recognizes the commands in the library, but when I try to use them, it gives me an error that says:

> the namespace is undefined

My question is - what is the best way to include a non-exporting (legacy) js library in a vue project?

`import * as test from "library.js"`

Comment: In the `main.js` (or something like that), write `import './path/to/library.js'`. If the library expose itself to `window` object, it will work. Then you can use it like `window.test` or just `test` as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

> The `webpack` compiler can understand modules written as `ES2015`
>   modules, `CommonJS` or `AMD`. However, some third party libraries may
>   expect global dependencies (e.g. `$` for `jQuery`). The libraries
>   might also create globals which need to be exported. These "broken
>   modules" are one instance where shimming comes into play.

[Reference](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/).

`import './path/to/library.js'`

Comment: I've tried that and i get "ReferenceError: xxx is not defined" for the namespace of the library.